# Table of random numbers (CLT).

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

I have a very interesting problem, but I don't have idea how to solve it.
How many numbers do we need to take from the table of random numbers to be sure( with probability at least $0.9$), that we have at least one even number.

I know, that I should use CLT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability to draw $n$ odd numbers in a row is $2^{-n}$, and we want this to be smaller than $0.1$. Hence four drawings are enough.

Comment: Using the CLT here would be overkill and possibly inaccurate.